# Update Options of a Select Element Dynamically using Knockout Js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, select, option

I am looking for updating a custom Select Option at Checkout.

```
 <select name="city" id="city" data-bind="
    options: availableCities,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsCaption: 'Select City',
    value: 'type',
    event:{change : cityselection}"
>
</select>
```

I have assigned availableCities as an *Observablearray* like below in the Js script

```
var availableCitiesdata = ko.observableArray([]);
```

My issue is I don't know how I could dynamically update *`availableCitiesdata`* to get options in the search element.

I did check out multiple articles, but all seem to be confusing to me personally.

Any sort of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you need to use availableCitiesdata in your data-bind options value instead of availableCities

Comment: Thank you @RakeshJesadiya , appreciate your help :) . Is it possible to bind a variable ?